# Foreach loop with multiple element in Twig template engine

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

I'm using Twig as template framework for my PHP web application.

I would like to know if there is a fast way to get many element in a foreach block.

This is my data:

```
users=>[
 ["name"=>"User1"],
 ["name"=>"User2"],
 ["name"=>"User3"],
 ["name"=>"User4"],
 ["name"=>"User5"],
 ["name"=>"User6"]
]
```

This would be a standard loop (each item):

```
<ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li>{{ user.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But this is what I need in block of **n** elements (in this example **n=3**)

```
<ul>
    <li>User1</li>
    <li>User2</li>
    <li>User3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>User4</li>
    <li>User5</li>
    <li>User6</li>
</ul>
```

Exists a fast way to do this in Twig or should I prepare the data in a different way with a one more subarray layer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like you need to use `batch` filter:

```
{% set items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] %}

<table>
{% for row in items|batch(3, 'No item') %}
    <tr>
        {% for column in row %}
            <td>{{ column }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

It will render:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>No item</td>
        <td>No item</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Source: [Twig Documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html)

Comment: Thank you. Batch was my answer!

Comment: The twig documentation link is dead. :-(